# Writing a loop to set value to 0 for bottom 20 rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large data set broken down into many blocks with 50 rows in each block. In Column J, I need to make the cell value equal to 0 for the last 20 rows in each scenario.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Forecast()

Const Block_sz As Long = 20
Dim rng, c

Set rng = Range("J2").Offset(-30, 0).Resize(Block_sz, 1)

    For Each c In rng.Cells

        c.Value = 0

    Next c

End Sub
```

This is the line I am getting my error from

```
Set rng = Range("J2").Offset(-30, 0).Resize(Block_sz, 1)
```

What I had tried to do is set my block size to 20 and use offset to start the range 30 rows down. However, this did not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

G

Comment: For rows, positive values offset down, negative offset up.

Answer (score 1):

A quick read of [MSDN - Range.Offset Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel) will help.

For *RowOffset*, "Positive values are offset downward, and negative values are offset upward".